# how do i use if statements in C?

Tags: c, chatbot

im trying to make a simple code similar to a chatbot, but I'm running into an issue with my code, can someone please help me with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char y[100];
    char w[100];
    char x[10] = "good";
    char z[10] = "bad";
    
    printf("Hi, what is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", y);
    printf("nice to meet you %s, how is your day so far?\n", y);
    scanf ("%s", w);
    if(strstr(y, x) != NULL) {
        printf("Oh, whats wrong?\n");
        scanf("%s", w);
        printf("Oh, I hope your day gets better.");
    }else if(strstr(y, z) != NULL) {
        printf("thats good!");
    }else {
        printf("ERROR: invalid input");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I get for the output, It does use some user input, so please keep that in mind.

```
Hi, what is your name?
seth
nice to meet you seth, how is your day so far?
good
ERROR: invalid input
```

Comment: `strstr("seth", "good")` yields `NULL`... `strstr("seth", "bad")` yields `NULL`.

Comment: You put the answer in `w`, not `y`.

Comment: If you are making a chatbot you'll probably want to enter more than a single word. The response to "Oh, whats wrong?" from `scanf("%s", w);` will stop scanning at the first whitespace character.

Comment: Memory for variable names has not been an issue for a long time. `y`, `w`, `x`, `z` could be changed to `name`, `response`, `answer1`, `answer2`.  Anything but  `y`, `w`, `x`, `z` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misplaced variables.

First, you are storing the user input into variable w, but you are not using that variable in your comparison. Second, you are not comparing it to the correct variable for input.

Here are the corrections with the old lines commented out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char y[100];
    char w[100];
    char x[10] = "good";
    char z[10] = "bad";
    
    printf("Hi, what is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", y);
    printf("nice to meet you %s, how is your day so far?\n", y);
    scanf ("%s", w);
    //if(strstr(y, x) != NULL) {
    if(strstr(w, z) != NULL) {
        printf("Oh, whats wrong?\n");
        scanf("%s", w);
        printf("Oh, I hope your day gets better.");
    //}else if(strstr(y, z) != NULL) {
    }else if(strstr(w, x) != NULL) {
        printf("thats good!");
    }else {
        printf("ERROR: invalid input");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this fixed the issue, thank you

Comment: It is good practice to add comments and indicate why code was changed. The way you have it now, this answer is only good for OP. By adding some comments in your code explaining why you changed certain parts, it is useful for future readers as well.

Comment: @sethh - If this _fixed the issue_ for you, consider clicking the hollow check-mark next to the answer.